# Randomly pick rows from a data.frame based on a column value

Tags: r, dataframe, function, random, dplyr

I was wondering if there is away to make my `expand.grid()` output show unequal rows for each unique `study` value (currently, each unique `study` value has 4 rows)?

For example, can we *randomly* pick some or all rows of `study == 1`, some or all rows of `study == 2`, and some or all rows of `study == 3`?

The number of rows picked from each study is completely random.

This is toy study, a functional answer is appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
(data <- expand.grid(study = 1:2, outcome = rep(1:2,2)))
arrange(data, study, outcome)
#   study outcome
#1      1       1
#2      1       1
#3      1       2
#4      1       2 #--- Up to here study == 1
#5      2       1
#6      2       1
#7      2       2
#8      2       2 #--- Up to here study == 2
#9      3       1
#10     3       1
#11     3       2
#12     3       2 #--- Up to here study == 3
```

Comment: How do you decide the randomness for each `study`?  Can you show some sample inputs and corresponding output to  the function that you expect?

Comment: @RonakShah, that is random too. You may pick all rows, or a few existing rows of a study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sample` `n()` for each `study` and select 1 random value.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(study) %>% sample_n(sample(n(), 1)) %>% ungroup
```

Comment: Looks like, the lifecycle of `sample_n()` family has been superseded. Can we use `slice_sample()` instead?

Comment: Nope. `slice_sample` needs `n` or `prop` to be fixed and they cannot be dynamic across groups. I raised an issue last year https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5478 about this but the `dplyr` developers have different opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this should work

```
data %>% 
  #Grouping by the variable study
  group_by(study) %>% 
  #Sampling 3 observations for each study
  sample_n(size = 3)
```